# Devolver un dato de un procedimiento almacenado en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure, oracle-11g

Tengo este procedimiento almacenado:

```sql
create or replace procedure spu_modificarTrabajador ( tnombre varchar2, tapellido varchar2, tid_cargo number, tdireccion varchar2, trut varchar2,tsueldo number, tcorreo varchar2, tcomuna number)
is
begin
    update TRABAJADOR
       set NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR=tnombre
           ,APELLIDO_TRABAJADOR=tapellido
           ,ID_CARGO=tid_cargo
           ,DIRECCION_TRABAJADOR=tdireccion
           ,RUT_TRABAJADOR=trut
           ,SUELDO=tsueldo
           ,CORREO_TRABAJADOR=tcorreo
           ,ID_COMUNA=tcomuna
     where RUT_TRABAJADOR=trut;
end;
```

Mi problema es que necesito que me retorne algún dato que me valide la modificación.

Comment: ¿Valide cómo? ¿podrías aclarar un poco a qué te estás refiriendo con validar en este caso? ¿Cuáles son los valores esperados como resultado? ¿Cuándo se deberían obtener esos valores y por qué? El botón para [edit] está al pie de tu pregunta. ¿Podrías agregar esta información?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente, para que te retorne variables mediante la palabra clave **OUT** y así indicar que es un parámetro de salida (la palabra clave **IN** es opcional y solo indica que el parámetro es de entrada). En mi ejemplo de abajo el procedimiento retorna la cantidad de registros afectados por la actualización, un código de error y un mensaje de error en caso de alguna excepción no controlada. El bloque **EXCEPTION** se ejecutará cuando ocurra una excepción, ya sea lanzada intencionalmente o no. En caso de una excepción no controlada se ejecutará el bloque **OTHERS** y el código y mensaje de error de Oracle quedarán asignados en las variables **SQLCODE** y **SQLERRM**. Espero te sea de ayuda. Casi todos mis procedimientos almacenados siguen la misma estructura.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spu_modificarTrabajador (
    tnombre IN VARCHAR2,
    tapellido IN VARCHAR2,
    tid_cargo IN NUMBER,
    tdireccion IN VARCHAR2,
    trut IN VARCHAR2,
    tsueldo IN NUMBER,
    tcorreo IN VARCHAR2,
    tcomuna IN NUMBER,
    reg_afectados OUT NUMBER,
    cod_err OUT NUMBER,
    msg_err OUT VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
    cod_err := 0;
    msg_err := 'OK';

    UPDATE trabajador
    SET nombre_trabajador = tnombre,
        apellido_trabajador = tapellido,
        id_cargo = tid_cargo,
        direccion_trabajador = tdireccion,
        rut_trabajador = trut,
        sueldo = tsueldo,
        correo_trabajador = tcorreo,
        id_comuna = tcomuna
    WHERE rut_trabajador = trut;

    reg_afectados := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        reg_afectados := 0;
        cod_err := SQLCODE;
        msg_err := SQLERRM;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, yo utilizaría el BEGIN / EXCEPTION de PLSQL, que es parecido a un bloque Try / Catch en otros lenguajes. (En el Begin pones lo que quieres intentar hacer, y al final del Begin retornas el valor que desees, y en el Exception pones lo que quieres que se devuelva si ha habido algún error).

Aquí te dejo el enlace a la página oficial con la documentación: [Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)

Aún así te dejo un ejemplo aquí:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tabla_inventada
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- Si no encuentra ningún dato entraría aquí.
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!!